# Host Header Attack

Tags: php, http-headers

Boa noite, gostaria de saber porque o Acunetix dá um alerta vermelho quando eu faço um scan no meu site: "Host header attack"
 E não é só o meu não, muitos sites acusam disso e não achei falando muita coisa falando sobre isso na net e eu não entendo muito queria saber como eu faço pra não dar esse alerta? Valeu pessoal.

Comment: Esse tal de acunetix tem alguma página de documentação que explique o significado dos alertas que ele emite?

Comment: Tem sim: http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/automated-detection-of-host-header-attacks/